# Ancestry and Family Search uploaded media items

Tags: ancestry.com, familysearch.org, photo, documents, images

When I upload media items usually .jpg's to either Ancestry and Family Search they get reduced in file size from 10 to 60%. When they are uploaded they are under the required files size.
Is there a way to stop the reduction of file size?

Comment: I would imagine that this is something you need to take up with Ancestry as they know how their API works. An alternative is to use PNG image format as it can’t be compressed. But as a result some images may exceed 15MB.

Comment: Likely, no. I guess my question to you is, why do you care? Why is that an issue to you? jw.